# Can one turn all the light bulbs with m switches or not

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given `n` bulbs, initially, all bulbs are off and `m` switches, each switch controls a range of light bulbs `l` to `r` (both inclusive)

We neeed to determine if it is possible to switch on all the bulbs using any of `m` switches any no of time.

The answer can be yes if one can or can be no if one cant.

E.g first given `n` then `m` and then next `m` lines give the range which the switch controls. In the following example `n = 5` and `m = 2`.

```
5 2
1 2
3 5
```

here answer is yes because 2 switches can control all the bulbs. and can be turned on.

Second example

```
5 2
1 2
3 4
```

here the answer is no because one of the bulbs is not controlled by any switch.

What I did is declare an array count with size `m` and for each switch I counted how many bulbs it control by `(r-l +1)` if the sum of count is equal to `n` then yes else no.

But only sample test cases are passed rest all fails.

Note: Ranges might intersect

If ranges intersect for example

```
1 3 
3 5
```

The answer is no because when one turn the second switch on the 3 rd bulb flip from on to off

So the answer will be no.

Comment: Can ranges intersect? Also, please edit the title and the post (no 'u' stuff, capital letters, etc.)?

Comment: I'm guessing that ranges can overlap. For example `1 3` and `3 5`. In that case, what happens if both switches are ON?

Comment: there is no such thing mentioned whether ranges  can overlap or not but i guess they would be intersecting that is what makes the question hard else it would have ran just by simple counting.

Comment: I agree. So if the first line is `5 2` and that's followed by `1 3` and `3 5`, is the answer YES or NO?

Comment: For `1 3` and `3 5` the answer is `NO`.
@raghavsingh, Are any changes happening to the post?

Comment: @dyukha If you think the presentation of the question needs to be improved, you can suggest an [edit].

Comment: Well, I just consider this kind of presentation disrespectful. I don't see why I should clean up someone's mess.

Comment: That's fine, and your first comment is certainly ok. But after that, if you aren't satisfied with the response from the OP, the correct thing to do is downvote and move on.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply @dyukha the answer will be no because when u flip second switch the 3rd bulb will turn off from on

Comment: This seems to be a homework

Comment: Thanks for the nice question! It made me do some interesting research.

Comment: I can't see a relation to any programming language: [tag:java] should not be a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see this problem as an instance [XOR-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#XOR-satisfiability) problem, though it is more general than the problem posed here, that's one way to go.

Just to gain some intuition I provide a very simple example. Suppose you have systems of three switches and three bulbs like this:

```
S    B
1    1, 3    // toggles bulbs 1 and 3
2    1, 2
3    1, 2, 3
```

It is equivalent to have the following formula, which we want to satisfy:

> (x<sub>1</sub>^x<sub>2</sub>^x<sub>3</sub>)&(x<sub>1</sub>^x<sub>2</sub>)&(x<sub>1</sub>^x<sub>3</sub>).

And now we want to satisfy this formula. We start with writing it as system of boolean equations modulo 2:

```
 |1 1 1|   |x_1|   |1|
 |0 1 1| * |x_2| = |1| mod 2
 |1 0 1|   |x_3|   |1|
```

Now solve it with [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

First, add the first and the second rows to the third:

```
1 1 1   1      1 1 1   1
0 1 1   1   -> 0 1 1   1
1 0 1   1      0 0 1   1   // for RHS, 1+1+1 = 1 mod 2
```

Second, back-substitute: x<sub>1</sub> = 0, x<sub>2</sub> = 0, x<sub>3</sub> = 1, which is obviously the answer.

So, the main complexity here is to program Gaussian elimination process.

Comment: Good description (I had a similar solution, but failed to notice relation to linear systems). It also can be noted that thanks to the fact that our switches cover segments (not random subsets) you can reduce time from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2)`.